# How can i make a multiple drag and drop upload field that supports dragging from itunes?

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone knows this?
we prefer html5 and jquery over other ways.

Comment: Are you trying to drag a song from iTunes to a web app?

Answer (score 0):

I googled 'AJAX JQUERY MULTIPLE FILE UPLOAD' clicked on the first result, and was brought to the git-hub with working demo of exactly that which you asked for. It should also be noted that you cannot have auto-sync set up if you want to keep the ability to drag and drop files from/to iTunes...

> http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: What is auto-sync and why is that impossible with itunes?